# How to send a proactive notification in a specific channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm developing a Teams app, I'm trying to send the proactive messages in channel, is it possible?
I tried to send messages in 1:1 scope that works fine.

```
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet][1]
```

Can someone help me with channel implementation?

Comment: You can send proactive message to channel. You can fetch the channel data from the activity. Could you please go through the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet#creating-a-channel-conversation) Also could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp/blob/32c39268d60078ef54f21fb3c6f42d122b97da22/template-bot-master-csharp/src/dialogs/examples/teams/ProactiveMsgTo1to1Dialog.cs)

Comment: Thanks Nikitha I will check it